# gets the default wallpapers of the device

Tags: android

I am trying to create a sample program which gets the default wallpapers of the device and set the one selected by app..i m able to set the image  as wallpaper from res/drawable folder ,but i m not getting any idea to access the default wallpapers.. Does anyone have any idea/example on how to do this?
Thanks